# Private VPN IP address for home webserver different than IP shown in whatismyip.com

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I maintain a very small website via my home web server. It is very lightly used, being of interest only to those within my community. The server runs openvpn so the website can be accessed via its own unique public IP address (no home router forwarding, etc.). That numerical address is linked via DDNS to a domain name registered by Google Domains.

If I utilize my VPN provider's server in Sweden (where they're based), then the webserver's VPN IP address listed in `ipconfig` is the same as what's shown at `whatismyip.com`, and all is good: The site can be accessed via the domain name, as well as directly though the VPN IP address.

However, to allow the pages to load as fast as possible, I wanted to switch to one of my VPN company's servers in USA. But when I do so, the VPN IP address in `ipconfig` is very different than `whatismyip.com`. For example, `ipconfig` will show something like `10.10.66.136`, but `whatismyip.com` shows something like `74.115.214.129`.

I then notify Google Domain of the IP change for the domain name (using the address shown at `whatismyip.com`). But I am unable to access the website either through the domain address or the specific VPN IP. What's going on?

Comment: Well, does the provider promise you a public IP regardless of the region of the VPN server is in anyway? You should contact the provider. No point asking here.

Answer (score 0):

It's all working as it should. `10.10.66.136` is a private IP address you get assigned from your work's VPN Server making you part of the VPN-LAN (in layman's terms). Since it is a private IP address it can not be reached "from the internet".

`74.115.214.129` is most likely your companie's router's public IP (if your internet traffic goes through your companie's VPN, which is usually the case unless you e.g. use a split tunnel).

This means queries to `74.115.214.129` will have to be answered by the router or if a port forward is set to another system it will have to be answered by the other system. Hence if you want `74.115.214.129` to be answered by your server a port forward needs to be put in place (and you need to make sure that if your "VPN IP" changes the port forward is updated to the new address as well).

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further, it appears that my VPN provider intentionally has open ports from their Swedish server, while all their servers in other countries have port forwarding.

Comment: So you are getting `10.10.66.136` from your VPN provider and not from your work VPN?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "work VPN"

Comment: Never mind, I missunderstood your question. That's why I didn't answer correctly.

Comment: If it helped you anyway with the troubleshooting I would appreciate a +1. Don't forget to accept your own answer.